# Is it possible to display KDE and windows in full 3d?

Tags: kde, 3d

I think the name is pretty self explanatory...I have a samsung monitor that has an adapter and active 3d glasses. I want to know how I can connect it all together, and display KDE and all it's windows in full 3d. How would I do this? Is it even possible?